# Jupyter IPYNB Problems

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

so I'm trying to familiarize myself with the Jupyter Notebook and am running into issues.

When I run the following code in the normal .py file of my PyCharm IDE it runs perfect; however, if I run it in my notebook the [*] never disappears meaning it just continuously runs never ending. Any idea why that might be the case? all answers much appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd

train_file='C:\Users\DDautel\Anaconda2\PycharmProjects\Kaggle\Titanic\RUN.csv'
test_file='C:\Users\DDautel\Anaconda2\PycharmProjects\Kaggle\Titanic\RUN2.csv'
train=pd.read_csv(train_file)
test=pd.read_csv(test_file)


print train.describe()
print test.describe()
```

Comment: anyone have any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: How are you running your code? since if you are using `jupyter notebook` then you would have a `*.ipynb` file which you can run. You will not be running your `*.py` in notebook.

Comment: Couple of assumptions: you are running this on Python 2.7, and you have tried splitting up the lines on different cells to see which one is the problem right?

Comment: @Back2Basics Yeah I have tried it, it's importing pandas that isn't working for some reason.

Comment: @Back2Basics I have tried that. The problem seems to be importing pandas. It works in my normal python files; however, not in my notebook

Comment: And yes, it is python 2.7

Comment: Ahhh. Download and install Anaconda https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: yep, anaconda is what I'm running now. any ideas as why it still wouldn't work in the notebook?

Comment: Actually. It's working now. I am not quite sure why it was wrong but maybe it was running on my old python before I changed everything up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others gratification:

Glad it's solved.
Make sure python, ipython, jupyter from anaconda (using conda env's possibly) is in your path before others.  Order is important.